# .Net SDK for Biometric scanning

Tags: .net, biometrics

I am planning to implement a Biometric authentication system for Card less shopping

Purpose is to use the fingerprint scanning as one of authentication method for bank transaction

Am looking for a solution in DOT net that can be used to scan finger prints and as I researched could find [verifinger](http://neurotechnology.com/verifinger.html), [griaule](http://www.griaulebiometrics.com/new/content/gbs-forensic-edition/#sdk) as some of the good SDKs

I need a SDK that can perfectly scan the finger print even with images of different qualities/ clarity not only from finger print readers but also scanned images of finger prints

Please help me with which one would be a good choice

Regards
Sreekar

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways you can integrate a biometric authentication system with your existing platform for card less payments. One way is to develop an SDK for the .Net framework that will work with the hardware/scanner you are planning to use. But developing one is sometimes far more difficult because you have to keep in mind a lot of issues like operating system upgrade. The second and the more practically feasible solution is to go for an existing SDK that can be easily integrated into a system. With SDKs from reputable providers, you will not have to worry about upgrades or glitches. You can check out the M2SYS SDK. However, it is not free, in case you were looking for a free solution.

Answer (score -1):

Look at the digital persona sdk as well. They are implementing wsq file format which will give you compatibility in future with other readers. There is a once off fee for the development kit which is not that high and no licenses required. There is also a free version which allows for one to one matching of prints. 
There is also a lot of other nice stuff implemented such as identification over networks and recognition and take-on of users online which can be used free and is available in the digital persona web forums. 
You can use on windows and Linux and new model coming soon will give compatibility for hardware integrations. In my opinion they are one of the best desktop scanners with great support. They are also the most economical in the high performance scanners as far as cost is concerned. 
Full samples in a number of languages including c# and a very nice GUI is provided plus full documentation. Is very simple to implement in comparison to any other kit I have worked with.

Regards Warrick